# Realistic Car Controller unity. Проблема с освещением

Tags: unity3d, light

Проблема следующая: я расставил всевозможное освещение и индикаторы на машину в соответствии с документацией и туториалами разработчиков. На сцене весь свет отображается корректно, но стоит мне запустить игру, как любое освещение перестает работать. Пробовал создавать свет разными способами(с помощью интерфейса и вручную). При создании освещения через интерфейс выдает ошибку, но я не могу понять каким образом она влияет на работу освещения и как ее исправить. Скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RCC_LabelEditor.SetIcon (UnityEngine.GameObject gObj, UnityEngine.Texture2D texture) (at Assets/RealisticCarControllerV3/Editor/RCC_LabelEditor.cs:69)
RCC_LabelEditor.SetIcon (UnityEngine.GameObject gObj, RCC_LabelEditor+Icon icon) (at Assets/RealisticCarControllerV3/Editor/RCC_LabelEditor.cs:63)
RCC_EditorWindows.CreateHeadLight () (at Assets/RealisticCarControllerV3/Editor/RCC_EditorWindows.cs:178)
RCC_SceneGUI.OnScene (UnityEditor.SceneView sceneview) (at Assets/RealisticCarControllerV3/Editor/RCC_SceneGUI.cs:124)
UnityEditor.SceneView.CallOnSceneGUI () (at <8117508d098d40e7b6cab2e14abb2fdc>:0)
UnityEditor.SceneView.HandleSelectionAndOnSceneGUI () (at <8117508d098d40e7b6cab2e14abb2fdc>:0)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnGUI () (at <8117508d098d40e7b6cab2e14abb2fdc>:0)
UnityEditor.SceneView.OnSceneGUI () (at <8117508d098d40e7b6cab2e14abb2fdc>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 worldTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, System.Boolean canAffectFocus, System.Boolean verifyBounds) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, System.Boolean canAffectFocus, System.Boolean verifyBounds) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy.DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, System.Boolean imguiEventIsInitiallyUsed) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEventQueue () (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.OpenGate () (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate.Dispose () (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel.SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase e, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& eventHandled) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration+<>c.<.cctor>b__1_2 (System.Int32 i, System.IntPtr ptr) (at <08363d2dfe344c968bd1864d73bb6984>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& result) (at <04b2664316804d17bf325b884567dc2b>:0)
```

Использую плагин для Юнити RCC(Realistic Car Controller V3.5)

Comment: Замени картинку текстом...

Comment: @ksa, добавил код ошибки